# WordPress 3.5 how to determine if user is on category listing or category edit screen?

Tags: categories, theme-development

I have a custom bit of code that I need to place on the category edit screen but not on the manage categories screen.

Prior to WordPress 3.5, I was able to set a global $action variable to check for action="edit" and place my code.

The same action variable returns empty in 3.5

Comment: Don't set global variables. WordPress has hundreds, and you'll likely clash with them. Probably a `$action`variable was made global in 3.5 :)

Comment: Can you show the code you were using?

Answer (score -1):

```
if(is_admin() && isset($_GET['taxonomy']) && $_GET['taxonomy'] == 'category' && isset($_GET['tag_ID']) {
    // place your code here
}
```

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem. A code snippet is not an answer.